# React-dnd Module not found

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in react.. Following this [tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) I have 
successfully launch fresh App.

Also installed:

```
npm install --save react-dnd
npm install --save react-dnd-html5-backend
```

When I included files from this [tutorial](http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/)

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { DragSource } from 'react-dnd';
import { ItemTypes } from './Constants';
```

Gives me error:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './Constants' in 'C:\...\...\...\Apps\draggable\src'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a Constants folder where is exported ItemTypes?

Comment: no, in this tutorial nowhere is constants folder http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/

Comment: Well then this tutorial is kind of incomplete, as with npm install you are only installing react-dnd and react-dnd-html5-backend. But in code you are also importing { ItemTypes } from './Constants' which should be Constants.js component  located in the same folder where is exported function ItemTypes.. in your code you are missing that and that's why you get error.

Comment: Can you paste the directory structure of your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with your Constants file. You don't have any Constants.js in your current directory. Go through the link again and find the Constants.js creating

For the time, I have found some work around for this:

> Try creating a Constants.js in your current directory

Then add a constant to that directory like this:

```
export const ItemTypes = {
  KNIGHT: 'knight'
};
```

and save that file. Go through this link for further information.
http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-tutorial.html